# file Path is not identified in java in linux

Tags: java, linux, unix, path, classpath

I have a simple java file in linux.  I am executing another java program HelloWorld from my Parent Java class.

If I keep the class file in current directory it workds but if i keep in another directory it wont work. could you tell me what mistake I am doing here?

Working:

theProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java HelloWorld");

Notworking Below:

theProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -cp \"/home/sss/public_html/Project/WekaMLWorkbench/src/m85/\" HelloWorld");

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood your problem. It happens because of the regnoition problem in linux and java based environments.

Use this method in Runtime.

```
exec(String[] cmdArray)
```

Substituting the values.

```
theProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"java", "-cp" ,"/home/sss/public_html/Project/WekaMLWorkbench/src/m85/HelloWorld");
```